# L'Hospital's Rule for $u^{x}e^{-u}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Proving that**: $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$

$$\Gamma(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} = u^{x-1}e^u du$$

$$\Gamma(x+1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} = u^{x}e^u du$$

$$\Gamma(x+1) = -[u^x e^u]_{0}^{\infty} + x\Gamma(x)$$

$$\Gamma(x+1) = -[u^x e^u]_{0}^{\infty} + x\Gamma(x)$$

...

Then, finally I need to evaluating limits of $[u^x e^u]_{0}^{\infty}$:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} u^{x}e^{-u} = ??????$

Its zero... but why?

Comment: You have the integral wrong. The gamma function has a negative exponent on $e$.

Comment: Note that the limit should be taken over $u$ and not $x$. If the limit is taken over $x$, then the limit is infinite whenever $u$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming x is strictly an integer... I needed to apply L'hopital's rule x times recursively to find the limit:

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{d^x}{du^x} \bigg( \frac{u^x}{e^{u}} \bigg)$$

when you take the derivative x times for $u^x$ it turns out the result is x factorial.

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{x!}{(-1)^xe^{u}} \bigg)$$

thus, the denominator grows without bounds, numerator has a finite value... limit is zero....

Comment: Next time put this in your post. Add the edit sign.

Comment: And if $x$ is not an integer, it's less than some integer so the result still holds.